# Как вытащить переменную из функции?

Tags: python-3.x, функции

Я новичок в питоне, и поэтому у меня есть вопрос, на который я так и не нашел ответа (может, потому что плохо шерстил интернет).

В общем: у меня есть модуль в папке scripts, в которой есть файл utils.py, с таким классом:

```
class Utils:
    def get_sys_info(self):
        os = sys.platform

        return os
```

И есть файл main.py вне этой папки. Как вытащить переменную os, и использовать ее в файле main.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтоб подключить файл

```
import utils
```

из класса надо пулучить экземпляр чтоб работала переменная self

```
u = Utils()
```

функция с self запускается от экземпляра, её результат можно присвоить новой переменной

```
o = u.get_sys_info()
```

и вывести на экран

```
print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── main.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utils.py

1 directory, 3 files
```

---

***utils.py:***

```py
import sys


class Utils:
    def get_sys_info(self):
        os = sys.platform

        return os
```

***main.py:***

```py
from scripts.utils import Utils

os = Utils().get_sys_info()
```

Answer (score -1):

from (файл в котором переменная os) import os ИЛИ просто import (файл в котором переменная os)

И да перетащи main.py и utils.py,ну хотя это не точно,но вроде бы как нельзя импортировать файл который в другой папке,но это НЕ ТОЧНО!